# Error getting worksheet in Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to synchronize the filters of 2 pivot table(just from one way, change filters in pivot2 when filters in pivot1 are changed but not the opossite).
But I get this error when I try getting the sheet.

> st = Target.Worksheet
>
> Excecution Time Erro 438
>
> object doesnt support this property or method

The pivot in this worksheet might be changed in VBA Code of the event "WorkbookOpen" so it might not run when this worksheet is active, this is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

If Target.Name <> "pivot1" Then Exit Sub

Dim st As Worksheet
Dim pivot1 As PivotTable
Dim pivot2 As PivotTable

Set st = Target.Worksheet
Set pivot2 = st.PivotTables("pivot2")
Set pivot1 = st.PivotTables("pivot1")

For Each pf In pivot1.PageFields
    If pf.Name <> "Filter1" Then
        pivot2.PageFields(pf.Name).CurrentPage = pf.CurrentPage
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a worksheet is an object, you need to use the Set keyword i.e. `Set st = Target.Worksheet`

On another note, are these PivotTables based on the same data source? If so, no VBA necessary: Just add a Slicer and connect them via right clicking the Slicer and selecting Report Connections.

Comment: Even with Set, I still get the error "object doesnt support this property or method" . 
The excel something that is automatically generated by a program using EPPlus, everything must be done automatically so I can't use slicers,plus they dont have the same source.

Comment: Okay. Try  `set st = target.parent` or `Set st = worksheets(target.parent.name)`